# How to Extend ListView

Tags: java, android, oop, inheritance, constructor

Thanks for your time.

I have extended `ListView` as:

```
public class PrettyListView extends ListView {

    public PrettyListView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public PrettyListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public PrettyListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }
}
```

I am within the context of a fragment and attempt to instantiate it like this:

```
 listView = (PrettyListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.list);
```

I receive the following error:

```
 java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.ListView cannot be cast to com.sandbox.PrettyListView
```

Please help me understand how to override this error as this is a safe cast.

Thank you!

EDIT: XML As requested. Thanks again.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/wrapperView" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.sandbox.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: the problem is in your XML file, post it too

Comment: in layout of fragment view with id list is not instance of your PrettyListView

Comment: read the doc for custom views : http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/index.html

Comment: Why was this downvoted?  It seems a reasonable enough question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What the error says is that your `PrettyListView` is a `ListView` but a `ListView` is not your `PrettyListView`. Inside the xml where you declared the ListView, you have to declare your PrettListView:

```
   <com.sandbox.PrettyListView 
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:id="@+id/list" />
```

Comment: Wonderful.  Thank you for the attention to detail on the com.sandbox.* prefix.  A+!

Answer (score 0):

In your XML file you must use **PrettyListView** instead of **ListView**

Comment: First and foremost thank you for your answer.  The problem here is that while the inclusion of com.sandbox.* may be obvious to you, it was not to me and still threw an error.  Best of luck in Android though!